# Implementing a product key system?

Tags: key-management, software

Say I have a piece software that allows people to download a trial version that can then be unlocked.  Would the following steps below be an effective way to implement a key system for unlocking the software?

1. User can download trial of the software.  In order to purchase they need to go to the website and enter payment information and an email.
2. An MD5 hash is generated from this email.  This hash is stored in a DB controlled by me and also emailed to the purchaser.
3. User takes the hash from the email, enters it into the software.  The software sends this as part of a HTTP request to a web service I control.
4. The web service marks this hash as "used".  It then sends a response indicating that the software should unlock.  Once a hash is marked as "used" it cannot be used to unlock again.

Can anyone see any problems with this plan?  Is there a different method that I should be using for something like this?

Comment: You're trying to do DRM. DRM never actually works. Your DRM is especially bad. Anybody can effortlessly setup a small lab where they feed your software whatever response it needs to unlock.

Comment: Suggestions on how to make it better?  Also - I get that nothing will stop someone who really wants to steal the software, but I'd like to make it harder without spending the rest of my life implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would take me (and anyone with HTTP proxy) exactly 2 minutes to defeat this kind of protective measure.

The only effective protective measure for software is not to ship it to user. E.g. you can include only half of the functionality in the demo version. When user wants to upgrade to full version you take their money, give them one time link to download full version.

Or you could do part of the software as a service, depending on what it does, user can send the data to your server, and then you either perform the action or not depending if they are paying customers.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  In the first protective measure you suggest allowing them to download the full version after they pay.  What is to stop them from redistributing the software after they download it?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Nothing. You'll just have to trust that your software is good enough to make people _want_ to pay for it. Someone _will_ crack your protection.

Comment: I get that, but I'd at least try to make it somewhat difficult.  It seems like using your first method would make it easier to steal than what I am proposing.  In mine they would need to know how to use an HTTP proxy, but in yours once someone downloads it they can just give it to whomever right?  Just to clarify - I'm not trying to be a smart ass or disrespect your suggestion.  I appreciate your input and I am honestly asking which would be more secure.  Thanks!

Comment: Abe, it would be just as easy to make a patch for the software to just skip HTTP check. And while it requires certain technical knowledge - it only has to be done once and after that anyone can re-distribute the cracked copy. I'd suggest to concentrate on making good software. If it's good - people will pay.